# Koala and Omniauth-twitter don't go together

Tags: ruby, twitter, sinatra, omniauth, koala

I posted the same in github of Koala but noone answered to me so I put here.

So when I try to login with Twitter with Omniauth:

```
I, [2013-11-15T18:57:12.371006 #28412]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Request phase      initiated.
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2013 18:57:13] "GET /auth/twitter HTTP/1.1" 500 144366 0.9355
```

I have also a Koala login to facebook I don't use Omniauth for Facebook I just use Omniauth for twitter, If I don't require Koala is ok, but if I have both it generates:

```
undefined method `[]=' for #<Koala::Facebook::OAuth:0x00000001b03348>
~>In oauth.rb line 31
```

I'm using 1.6.0 version of Koala and Sinatra.

My code is:

```
#Facebook
get '/loginfb' do
    session['oauth'] = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new($APP_ID, $APP_SECRET, "#{request.base_url}/callbackfb")
    redirect session['oauth'].url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => ["publish_stream"])
end

get '/callbackfb' do
    session['access_token'] = session['oauth'].get_access_token(params[:code])
    registerUserFB() #Just register the user function
    redirect '/accounts'
end

#Twitter
#By defualt logs in with /auth/twitter
get '/auth/twitter/callback' do
    erb "<h1>#{params[:provider]}</h1><pre>#{JSON.pretty_generate(request.env['omniauth.auth'])}</pre>"
    p auth['credentials']['token']
end

get '/auth/failure' do
    erb "<h1>Authentication Failed:</h1><h3>message:<h3> <pre>#{params}</pre>"
end
```

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: I thought in delete the ruby before twitter progress and activate after login but I think this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another gem for logging with twitter called twitter_oauth yo can find [here](https://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth/tree/master)

For use with sinatra is quite simple:

```
#Sinatra stuff
require 'twitter_oauth'
#more sinatra stuff

$CONSUMER_KEY = '32423...'
$CONSUMER_SECRET = '...adads...'
$CALLBACK_URL = 'http://....'

tw_client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
    :consumer_key => $CONSUMER_KEY,
    :consumer_secret => $CONSUMER_SECRET
)

$request_token = tw_client.request_token(:oauth_callback => $CALLBACK_URL)

#sinatra routes
get '/logintw' do
    redirect $request_token.authorize_url
end

get '/callbacktw' do
    @access_token = $request_token.get_access_token :oauth_verifier =>     params[:oauth_verifier]
    p @access_token.params[:oauth_token]
    p @access_token.params[:oauth_token_secret]
    p @access_token.params[:screen_name]
    p @access_token.params[:user_id]
    redirect '/accounts'
end
#more sinatra routes
```

Is not the best solution but is one and for me works!

Thanks anyway.